# JS: Understanding when to use enum vs a constant?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have seen some files that export objects as constants such as :

```
export const LOOKUP_TABLE = {
   // 
}
```

and then files that export objects as `enum` but the data is shaped the same way as above:

```
export enum LOOKUP_TABLE = {
   // 
}
```

are they interchangeable or when should each be used?

Comment: `enum` is a Typescript thing.

Comment: enums offer improved type-safety since you can easily write things like `function doSomething(LOOKUP_TABLE enumValue) {...}`

Comment: There are various use cases for which enums and consts are more appropriate, and a whole lot of differing opinions.  I've linked several questions here, see their answers for specifics.